# How do I serialise a workflow from a single activity?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I want to be able to use the `XamlInjector` on a single custom activity created programmatically in order to dynamically mock it. Currently I have the following which throws `System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path`. from the injector. Any ideas how to make this work?

```
string serializedActivity = CreateXaml(new MyActivity()); //(Activator.CreateInstance(activityType));
var xamlInjector = new XamlInjector(serializedActivity);

private static string CreateXaml(object activity) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(builder);
    XamlWriter xamlWriter = ActivityXamlServices.CreateBuilderWriter(new XamlXmlWriter(writer, new XamlSchemaContext()));
    XamlServices.Save(xamlWriter, activity);
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

The following are examples of the xaml created:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><Delay xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" />`

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><CreateTemplate AuthenticationHeader="{x:Null}" BaseTdeUri="{x:Null}" CreatedTemplateId="{x:Null}" Password="{x:Null}" TemplateContent="{x:Null}" UserName="{x:Null}" xmlns="clr-namespace:XYZ.Workflow.TdeRestApi;assembly=XYZ.Workflow.Activities" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting idea - I should add an overload to XamlInjector that does this.

The reason you are getting the error is that the XamlInjector ctor is expecting a filename, not serialized xaml.

Comment: That was silly! I just changed the return type of CreateXaml to a Stream to make it work. However, it appears that while this solution would work for any kind of composite activity, for a NativeActivity with a child implementation that needs mocking XamlInjector just isn't clever enough to replace it.